# How to verify link partially in protractor?

Tags: protractor

I want to verify the link which is changing dynamically.

Html code :

```
<a href="https://..../v2/simCV/similarCVs?uniqId=713c7de2444bd8c078&amp;sid=2089261923" class="fl simCvLink" target="_blank">Similar Resumes 1</a>
```

In this link "uniqId" and "sid" variable name will not be changed.So how can i verify this variable name is present or not in protractor.

Here link text will also change i.e "Similar Resumes 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the attribute value and then build a logic to validate the id's - `uniqId` and `sid`. You can try something like below

```
    element(by.css('.simCvLink')).getAttribute('href').then(function _checkIDs(link) {
        //This is a pretty basic logic to check if the link has the expected values, but you can improve this with regex and fetch the ID's for better logic
        expect(link).toContain("713c7de2444bd8c078");
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = element.all(by.tagName('a')).filter(function(elem,index){
              return elem.getAttribute('href').then(function(href){
                return href.indexOf('uniqId=713c7de2444bd8c078&amp;sid=2089261923') > -1
                })
             }).count();

    if(count) console.log('element is present');
```